# C How can I count length of the longest continuous sequence of 0s in long variable?

Tags: c, while-loop, binary, numbers, long-integer

I have a simple function which counts me how many 0s are in long variable where is a binary representation of some positive integer value. But I need to implement a new feature which will return the length of the longest continuous sequence of 0s...

Function for count of 0s:

```
int nullSeq(long binn)
{
    int count=0;

    if(binn==0)
        return 1;

    while(binn!=0)
    {
        if ((binn & 1) == 0)
        {
            count++;
        }
        binn=binn >> 1;
    }

    return count;
}
```

F.e. the number 559. The binary representations of 559 is 1000101111. The 0 count function will return 4. The longest continuous sequence of zeros should be 3. Until now I unconsciously used the value of all zeros as a longest sequence. It worked for some numbers. But I need to implement a new function which will find the longest zero sequence.

Comment: Okay, why don't you try it? I think you can use the basic structure you have already. I think you'll need to add two variables, one to count the number of zeros currently visible, and one to keep track of the longest sequence seen. You just need to decide what to do when `(binn & 1)` is true, and what to do when it's false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're actually counting the *total* number of zeros you find.  You need to increase the counter when you find a 0 and set the counter to 0 when you find a 1, and you have to keep track of the largest value of the counter.

```
int nullSeq(long binn)
{
    int count=0, maxcount=0;

    if(binn==0) {
        return 1;
    }

    while(binn!=0) {
        if ((binn & 1) == 0) {
            count++;
            if (count > maxcount) {
                maxcount = count;
            }
        } else {
            count = 0;
        }
        binn=binn >> 1;
    }
    return maxcount;
}
```

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Good point.  Actually, I'll move the `count > maxcount` check into the "0" case to account for that.